# xPath extract a portion of attribute value

Tags: xpath

I have a Document like below. I can reach data-ext using xPath expression

```
/html/body/ol/li[1]/ol/li[1]/@data-ext
```

Is there any way I can get the value of our_id?

Or should I parse `string(/html/body/ol/li[1]/ol/li[1]/@data-ext)` as a separate json.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Contents</h1>
    <ol>
      <li data-ext='{"our_id":"45578107356868511506172578", "our_number":"1"}'>
        <span>Objective 1</span>
      </li>
    </ol> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling JSON separately may be a cleaner approach, specially depending on the tools you have available. But to get it using XPath only, you could use a combination of [`substring-before()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPath/Functions/substring-before) and [`substring-after()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPath/Functions/substring-after):

```
substring-before(substring-after(string(/html/body/ol/li[1]/@data-ext), 'our_id":"'), '", "our_number"')
```

Those functions return portions of the string based on the arguments. Click their names for further details and reference.

Answer (score -1):

No, xpath and json are separate concepts.

If you attempt to parse json using xpath, you could run into problems with escape sequences: `{"\"our_id":"12345", "our_id":"45578107356868511506172578",...`

This is why xpath and json should only be used how they are intended. Another issue is that xpath is not turing complete, I'm not sure whether you can write a safe parser, but I doubt it will be very fast even if you do.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant and trivial. One liners are not much appreciated here, unless you can provide some explanation like the answer below. This could well be a comment.

Comment: @PSL: Expanded the answer.